# Solve the following differential equation $x^2 y''-(2x+1)y'+(x+1)y=4e^{2x} x^2$!

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$x y''-(2x+1)y'+(x+1)y=4e^{2x} x^2$$
I got a hint to try to guess one solution.
I guess it should be $e^x$ , because the coefficients add up to 0, so $y''=y'=y$ should be one. So how does this help me? Can you please elaborate in details? I was told how it's done, but I just can't understand this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: do you understand why $e^{2x}$ is a better guess than $e^x$?

Comment: i think there is no nice solution for this equation

Comment: I'm sorry, I might have caused some confusion. $x y''-(2x+1)y'+(x+1)y=4e^{2x} x^2$ this is the equation, I wanted to write, but I made a typo. I already editted it.

Comment: @yanko no, sorry, I don't.

Comment: If you substitute $e^x$ to the left side you will get a polynomial times $e^x$, but you're looking for a polynomial times $e^{2x}$ . Make sense?

Comment: I wrote down the solution and I reach an easier differential equation. Unfortunately as Dr.Sonnhard Graubner said it doesn't seem to be a nice solution for this. Should I post the answer anyway?

Comment: So then, I will basically be left with something like $e^{2x}(x-1)=e^{2x}(4x^2)$, right? 
Can you please post your solution? I would be very grateful!

Comment: yes I believe you have a computation mistake but the situation is that both sides have a polynomial function times $e^{2x}$.  I post the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So as you said we guessed the solution is somehow related to $e^{2x}$. Now if you set $e^{2x}$ we get

Left side  is
$$(4x^2-2(2x+1)+(x+1))e^{2x}=(4x^2-3x-1))e^{2x}$$
Right side is
$$4x^2 e^{2x}$$

so we almost got the solution up to a polynomial error. Hence we would like to guess a more complicated solution, instead of $e^{2x}$ we can guess it is $P(x)e^{2x}$ for a function $P$.

Now substitue $P(x)e^{2x}$ and divide by $e^{2x}$ you get a differential equation involving only $P$

$$xP''(x)+(2x-1)P'(x)+(x-1)P(x)=4x^2$$

At this point I would (wrongly) guess that $P$ is a polynomial function, but as  Dr. Sonnhard Graubner said, it Doesn't seem to be a nice solution for this.